# How to define a C# class to deserialize a specific XML Expression

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, .net-4.0

my serialization/deserialization just works fine but i want to change the xml-File a littel bit to make it more human readable.
What i have now is:

```
<Options>
  <Option>
    <Key>Backup</Key>
    <RegEx>.exe%</RegEx>
  </Option>
</Options>
```

I want to write it like:

```
<Options>
  <Option key="Backup" regex=".exe%" />
</Options>


[Serializable]
public class Option
{
    //[XmlElement("key")]
    public EOptions Key;
    //[XmlElement("regex")]
    public string RegEx;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Key.ToString();
    }
}

...
public List<Option> Options;
```

I google it since a hour and try a lot, but nothing works.

Comment: How about XmlAttributeAttribute? I find it hard to believe you didn't find that when searching. What search phrases did you try, out of curiosity?

Comment: XmlAttribute was the first i have tried. but i do not know why it did not work. maybe some type of typo.
and Google: hmm if you do not know the name of things its quit complicated to google it ;) i tried "xml key value" and so on. and than i tried every property from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/3dkta8ya.aspx

Comment: btw: you all made my day

Comment: It *probably* didn't work because you didn't have the right namespace imported. Could have mixed it up with the regular XmlAttribute class. Just a thought for another time. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `XmlElement` by `XmlAttribute`.

```
[Serializable]
public class Option
{
    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public EOptions Key;
    [XmlAttribute("regex")]
    public string RegEx;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Key.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, Beat me by a couple of minutes. I really should stop commenting and just giving answers. =)

Answer (score 0):

You use the [`XmlAttributeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx) class instead of `XmlElementAttribute`.

```
[Serializable]
public class Option
{
    [XmlAttribute("key")]
    public EOptions Key;
    [XmlAttribute("regex")]
    public string RegEx;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Key.ToString();
    }
}
```